# "background-img" problem in sass and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, sass

I Want To put a banner(big img) after navbar in my website, i use React js
this Error happend when put the img in same folder of js file
[image]

and when I tried to put the img in "Public" folder this erroe happen also
[image]

what is the solution please?

Comment: Did you use create-react-app template or you config your react app from scratch by yourself?

Comment: Yes from scratch by myself

Comment: Have you install ```file-loader``` plugin and added file loader config to your webpack config?

Comment: I don’t understand what you say,

Comment: I just use Reactjs and sass, must I use webpack?

Comment: You should read more about ```file-loader``` here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/